# How do I make a texture pack with multiple models for one "block"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I've made a few models for different varieties of a block, I want to make a texture pack that allows me to switch between all the models depending on something like naming it a certain name with an anvil (or any other way if that's not possible). Any help would be appreciated